# List combination of numbers which have same sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
**N** is a prositive number
```

Need list of scenarios which have sum equal `N`

For example if `N=4`

```
ScenarioId     Value
----------     -----
1              1
1              1
1              1
1              1
2              2
2              1
2              1
3              2
3              2
4              3
4              1
5              4
```

above  list is required. If you sum by ScenarioId all sum must equal to `N`

#### UPDATE

Here is my own solution. however, I am not sure about the multiplication of two different number sets would not be equal at any time.

## My current question is

Is there any possibilities `a + b + c = d + e + f` and `a * b * c = d * e * f`

[Test link is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7850ceb885e0880cb46e9cff5f5ecdde)

```
    DECLARE @N int = 4;

    SELECT 
    [Value] = CAST(number + 1 as tinyint) 
    INTO #Values
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE number < @N
    AND [Type] = 'p'

    ;WITH COMBINATIONS AS(
       SELECT ScenarioKey = CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(MAX)), [Value], Total = 0, Multipication = 1, MemeberCount = 0
       FROM #Values
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ScenarioKey = ISNULL(S.ScenarioKey, '') + IIF(S.ScenarioKey IS NULL, '', N'-') + CAST(P.[Value] AS nvarchar(10)), S.[Value], Total = S.Total + P.[Value], Multipication = S.Multipication * P.[Value], MemeberCount = MemeberCount + 1
       FROM #Values P
       JOIN COMBINATIONS AS S ON S.Total < S.[Value]
    ),
    SCENARIOS AS(
       SELECT
        ScenarioKey
       ,ScenarioId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ScenarioKey)
       ,[Value]
       FROM
       (
        SELECT 
         ScenarioKey 
        ,[Value]
        ,Multipication
        ,MemeberCount
        -- this will prevent dublications. because 1 * 2 * 3 = 3 * 2 * 1
        -- however, I am not sure about multipication of two different number sets would not be equal any time
        ,RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Value],Multipication,MemeberCount ORDER BY [Value],ScenarioKey)
        FROM COMBINATIONS
        WHERE Total = @N
      ) X
      WHERE RowNo = 1 AND [Value] = @N
    )
    SELECT
     R.ScenarioId
    ,[Value] = S.[value]
    FROM SCENARIOS R
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(R.ScenarioKey, '-')) S


    DROP TABLE #Values
```

Comment: SQL is not an appropriate language for this type of operation. It is possible, but it is not really appropriate.

Comment: We love that you're here and we'd like to see your code so we can help you.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: In your example ScenarioId=1 doesn't meet your condition

Comment: Definitely not the job for SQL.

Comment: Are there additional rows for each scenario (which would otherwise make the sum greater than 4)?

Comment: What is your SQL server version?

Comment: SQL 2017 @Zhorov

Comment: What is the largest `N` value you would calculate for?

Comment: @iamdave I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun With SQL, you will require recursion to achieve this task, which SQL is not very good at.  Any requirement over a certain size of `N` will take a very long time to resove.  As mentioned in other comments, unless you want to only calculate up to around `N = 200` (Which in my solution returns 681,651 rows) other tools are much better suited.

Comment: @iamdave I am not agree with SQL is not a good choice for this type of task. SQL is better than `C#` or `Javascript` for this type of recursive job. I must be sure about results. And just will produce results for one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too long for comment, so I post this as an answer. I want to note, that this is a static example, but I hope it can be easily translated as a dynamic statement.

Steps are written as comments in the statement:

```
WITH rcte AS
(
   -- Recursive query to generate all numbers from 1 to 4
   SELECT 0 AS Number
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT Number + 1
   FROM rcte
   WHERE Number < 4
), permutations AS (
   -- All possible permutations with sum equal to 4
   -- There is additional column DuplicateMarker. 
   -- It will be used later, because 0,0,0,4 and 0,4,0,0 are the same
   SELECT 
      t1.Number AS Number1,
      t2.Number AS Number2,
      t3.Number AS Number3,
      t4.Number AS Number4,
      CONCAT(LTRIM(STR(t1.Number)), '.', LTRIM(STR(t2.Number)), '.', LTRIM(STR(t3.Number)), '.', LTRIM(STR(t4.Number))) AS DuplicateMarker
   FROM rcte t1, rcte t2, rcte t3, rcte t4
   WHERE (t1.Number + t2.Number + t3.Number + t4.Number) = 4
), duplicates AS (
   -- Get data with splitted DuplicateMarker column
   SELECT *
   FROM permutations
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(DuplicateMarker, '.')) t
), results AS (
   -- Get unique combinations
   -- WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY) will order strings and 0.0.0.4 and 0.4.0.0 will be the same
   SELECT DISTINCT STRING_AGG([value], '.') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [value]) AS ScenarioValue
   FROM duplicates
   GROUP BY Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4
)
SELECT 
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY r.ScenarioValue) AS ScenarioID,
   s.[value]
FROM results r
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(r.ScenarioValue, '.')) s
WHERE [value] <> '0'
```

Output:

```
ScenarioID  value
1           4
2           1
2           3
3           2
3           2
4           1
4           1
4           2
5           1
5           1
5           1
5           1
```

Update:

Thanks to @AndriyM's comment, I've made some changes and now you can eliminate string manipulations:

```
WITH rcte AS
(
   -- Recursive query to generate all numbers from 0 to 4
   SELECT 0 AS Number
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT Number + 1
   FROM rcte
   WHERE Number < 4
), combinations AS (
   -- All different combinations with sum equal to 4
   SELECT 
      t1.Number AS Number1,
      t2.Number AS Number2,
      t3.Number AS Number3,
      t4.Number AS Number4,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Number, t2.Number, t3.Number, t4.NUmber) AS ScenarioID
   FROM rcte t1, rcte t2, rcte t3, rcte t4
   WHERE 
      ((t1.Number + t2.Number + t3.Number + t4.Number) = 4) AND
      (t1.Number <= t2.Number) AND
      (t2.Number <= t3.Number) AND 
      (t3.Number <= t4.Number)
)
SELECT c.ScenarioID, v.[value]
FROM combinations c
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (c.NUmber1), (c.Number2), (c.Number3), (c.Number4)) AS v ([value])
WHERE v.[value] > 0
```

Update 2:

Approach using dynamic statement - probably not the best approach, but is based on statement from first update:

```
-- Set your @n value
DECLARE @n int
SET @n = 4

-- Declarations
DECLARE @combinationsSelect nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @combinationsRowNumber nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @combinationsFrom nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @combinationsWhere1 nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @combinationsWhere2 nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @combinationsValues nvarchar(max)

SET @combinationsSelect = N''
SET @combinationsRowNumber = N''
SET @combinationsFrom = N''
SET @combinationsValues = N''
SET @combinationsWhere1 = N''
SET @combinationsWhere2 = N''

-- Generate dynamic parts of the statement
;WITH numbers AS
(
   SELECT 1 AS Number
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT Number + 1
   FROM Numbers
   WHERE Number < @n
)
SELECT 
    @combinationsSelect = @combinationsSelect + N', t' + LTRIM(STR(Number)) + N'.Number AS Number' + LTRIM(STR(Number)),
    @combinationsRowNumber = @combinationsRowNumber + N', t' + LTRIM(STR(Number)) + N'.Number',
    @combinationsValues = @combinationsValues + N', (c.Number' + LTRIM(STR(Number)) + N')',
    @combinationsFrom = @combinationsFrom + N', rcte t' + LTRIM(STR(Number)),
    @combinationsWhere1 = @combinationsWhere1 + N'+ t' + LTRIM(STR(Number)) + N'.Number ',
    @combinationsWhere2 = @combinationsWhere2 + 
        CASE
            WHEN Number = 1 THEN N''
            ELSE N'AND (t' + LTRIM(STR(Number-1)) + N'.Number <= t' +  + LTRIM(STR(Number)) + N'.Number) '
        END
FROM 
    numbers
SET @combinationsSelect = STUFF(@combinationsSelect, 1, 2, N'')
SET @combinationsRowNumber = STUFF(@combinationsRowNumber, 1, 2, N'')
SET @combinationsValues = STUFF(@combinationsValues, 1, 2, N'')
SET @combinationsFrom = STUFF(@combinationsFrom, 1, 2, N'')
SET @combinationsWhere1 = STUFF(@combinationsWhere1, 1, 2, N'')
SET @combinationsWhere2 = STUFF(@combinationsWhere2, 1, 4, N'')

-- Dynamic statement
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm =
    N'WITH rcte AS (
       SELECT 0 AS Number
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT Number + 1
       FROM rcte
       WHERE Number < ' + LTRIM(STR(@n)) +
    N'), combinations AS (
       SELECT ' + 
          @combinationsSelect +
          N', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @combinationsRowNumber + N') AS ScenarioID
       FROM ' + @combinationsFrom +
       N' WHERE ((' + @combinationsWhere1 + N') = ' + LTRIM(STR(@n)) + ') AND ' + @combinationsWhere2 + 
    N')
    SELECT c.ScenarioID, v.[value]
    FROM combinations c
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES ' + @combinationsValues + N') AS v ([value])
    WHERE v.[value] > 0'

-- Execute dynamic statement
EXEC (@stm)
```

Comment: I found a solution like yours. It seems that there is no solution without splitting scenario key. Thanks.

Comment: Nice method, although it might be more efficient to exclude the duplicates differently, by way of replacing the cross joins with triangular joins. [Here's an example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9602c558e07c62509f3b192f9e7e52ed).

Comment: @MehmetOtkun Thanks to AndriyM comment and example, I've added another approach, without string manipulations.

Comment: @Zhorov, @AndriyM I checked your solution true, but actually, it is not true. You just think about when `N = 4`. However, `N` is dynamic.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun If your comment is about how to generate dynamic statement for different `N` value, check updated answer.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun About the numbers:  `1 + 9 + 10 = 2 + 3 + 15 = 20` and `1 * 9 * 10 = 2 * 3 * 15 = 90`. I suppose there are others.

Comment: @Zhorov Thank you for number example

Comment: @iamdave I couldn't test your solution beacuse I don't have `fn_StringSplit4k`

Comment: @Zhorov I checked your solution true again. However, it seems slower than my solution. But I must find a way to make singular multiplication of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sample data like below

[image]

You can write query like below

```
Declare @N int =4

Select T.*
From #T T
    cross apply (
                select S, SUM(V) Total
                From #T
                Group By S) Totals
Where Totals.Total=@N and T.S = Totals.S
```

Comment: I believe the only input in the question is `N=4`